# python как с помощью selenium использовать прокси

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

как с помощью selenium использовать proxy в firefox

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Jack_oS Абсолютно нормальный вопрос, в чем проблема?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor проблема в том, что он не соответствует формату СО: если автор не потрудился набрать в поиске "selenium proxy" и перейти на [первую же ссылку](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/) с официальной документацией, где собственно и приведен указанный вами кусок кода, не попробовал его запустить и задать конкретный вопрос по проблеме, то  и дальше продолжит плодить вопросы, еще и вас винить в том, что у него "не работает", т.к. вы не учли в ответе использование прокси с авторизацией ;)

Comment: @Jack_oS 1. Не надо посылать в гугл. 2. Вопрос полезен. 3. Первая ссылка ­— enSO — благодаря SO есть куча примеров разного кода, гораздо больше, чем в любых доках ⇒ вопрос полезен.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor ок, не шлем в гугл, можно прямо в ruSO [послать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=selenium+proxy) )

Comment: @Jack_oS Ну так и оставьте ссылку или закройте как дупликат, если есть достаточно похожие вопросы. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "<HOST:PORT>"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",

}

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
    # Open URL
    driver.get("https://selenium.dev")
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973834/python-selenium-proxy)

Comment: а с помощью этого кода будут работать прокис с авторизацией?

Comment: @main Не пробовал, не уверен. XD

Comment: а есть еще код для прокси с авторизацией? XD

Comment: @main https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304253/how-to-set-proxy-authentication-user-password-using-python-selenium